# Requesting PHP variable inside include, defined outside include

Tags: php, variables, include

Bit of a problem here, I have a file with the following code:

```
<?php 
$kvkvariable = 000050650459;   
include("../../../../../../httpdocs/profiel/indextemplate.php"); 
?>
```

Inside the included PHP file, I need `$kvkvariable`. However, when I echo this variable it's not showing the number I want it to show?

If I place the defining code of the `$kvkvariable` inside `indextemplate.php` it works fine. I thought including was the same as pasting the code in the same file? How do I fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

indextemplate.php immediatly starts with this:

```
<?php

echo "Dit is kvk: ".$kvkvariable."";
```

It gives the following result:

```
Dit is kvk: 1337893
```

To be honest with you, I have no idea where he gets that number!?

Comment: Could you add the code of `indextemplate.php`? You're quite right about how includes work, so it might be an issue of scope.

Comment: The scope should be the same as the included file. Are you using namespaces?

Comment: I guess he is talking about global scope

Comment: Are you sure the file is included properly? Change include with require and check for errors

Comment: "when I echo this variable it's not showing the number I want it to show?" what number is it showing?

Comment: @Daniel - if he's using it in a function, `$kvkvariable` isn't going to be in scope. Without seeing the code, though, it's just a guess.

Comment: Not in a function, just a simple echo at the beginning of the file. I'm sure the include works fine, because I do see the echo en some parts of the page.

Comment: @user1555076 - have a look at my answer.

Comment: @andrewsi, thanks mate, but the solution were double quotes around the numer, my bad..

Comment: @user1555076 - that's because putting it in quotes turns it into a string, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my own question was fairly simple, use "" around the number defining the variable! My bad.. Maybe this helps someone out!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$kvkvariable = 000050650459;   
include("../../../../../../httpdocs/profiel/indextemplate.php"); 
?>
```

When PHP sees a number beginning with a 0, it assumes it's octal - and if you run 000050650459 through an octal to decimal converter, it gives you 1337893.

So your include is working as expecting; it's PHP's variable typing that's not doing what you expect.

Comment: Absolutely true! Double quotes around the number solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
<?php
$kvkvariable = 000050650459;   
include( "../../../../../../httpdocs/profiel/indextemplate.php?myvar=" . $kvkvariable ); 
?>
```

And you treat the variable inside your include as `$_GET[ 'myvar' ]`

Then your second file should be like this:

```
<?php
echo "Dit is kvk: " . $_GET[ 'myvar' ] . "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [php's `global` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
<?php 
global $kvkvariable;
$kvkvariable = 000050650459;   
include("../../../../../../httpdocs/profiel/indextemplate.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the solution, I'm not using it in a function, just a simple echo ;)